# Create multiple sources according to descriminating index using reduce and scan

Tags: rx-java, reduce, collect

have a stream which get gather data as response from its receptors.

so assuming i have n receptors, in the frame data received i'm able to know from which receptor index it was received and perform a filter and create a new source for each one as following.

-------a1------b1-----c1----a2-----a3----c2----b2-

-------a1-----------------a2-------a3-------------

---------------b1------------------------------b2-

----------------------c1---------------c2---------

For each receptor :

Knowing that each data packet has a timestamp. At this stage :

1. i want to computes the delay between each two packet and calculate the sum of delta
2. Create a stream of deltas and calculate the cumulated delay within each two seconds from a sample of 3 deltas
3. Finally, create a stream of delays where i take only the last emmited delay from each receptor.

Here where i'm :

```
List<Integer> indexes = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5);
    for(int receptorIndex : indexes) {
        observeSource(data, receptorIndex)
        .map(messages -> computesDelay(store, messages.get(1), messages.get(0)))
        .buffer(2000L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 3)
        .map(periods -> {
            Long delta = 0L;
            for(Long period : periods)
                delta += period;
            return delta;
        })
        .scan((x,y) ->  {return x+y;})
        .takeLast(1)
        .reduce((seed, value) -> {
            return seed + value;
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

public static long computesDelay(Map<String, Long> list, Data one, Data another){
        long expectedDelay = list.get(one.getMessage()) - list.get(another.getMessage());
        long effectiveDelay = one.getTimestamp() - another.getTimestamp();
        return effectiveDelay - expectedDelay;
    }

    public static Observable<List<Data>> observeSource(Observable<Data> data, int ReceptorIndex) {
        return data
        .filter(receptor -> receptor.getIndex() == ReceptorIndex)
        .buffer(2,1)
        .filter(list -> list.size() == 2);
    }
```

The problem is that when i'm using `reduce` or `takeLast(1)` after the scan it render 0 element.

What i am missing here guys.

I want the final output as following **(case a)**:

------a1------b1-----c1----a2-----a3----c2----b2--------a4---------

-------a1-----------------(a1,a2)-------(a2,a3)---------(a3,a4)----

----------------------------2-------------1----------------6--------

---------------------------9-----------------